# given we walk on the integer line with prob of 0.5 to go -1 or +1(random walk). If we start at 0 what is the probability we get to 100 before -1?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

given we walk on the integer line with prob of 0.5 to go -1 or +1(random walk).
If we start at 0 what is the probability we get to 100 before -1?

my attempt

$a_{i,100}$ the probability to get from i to 100.
so $a_{0,100}=0.5a_{1,100}$ ,  $a_{1,100}=0.5(a_{0,100}+a_{2,100})$ and so on.. can I assume that $a_{i,100}$ are equal except for $i=0$?

Comment: No - $a_{i,100}$ is an increasing function of $i$ as you are more likely to reach $100$ first if you start close to it.  A shortcut would be to spot that it is a linear function of $i$ since $a_{i,100}-a_{i-1,100}=a_{i+1,100}-a_{i,100}$

Comment: @Henry could you write a solution please :)?

Comment: convxy: Some people on this site have developed an attitude to answers that I regard as close to bullying, so for questions like this I tend to restrict myself to comments

Comment: Can you see $a_{100,100}=1$? Now you can solve the equations, since they form an arithmetic progression.